# VueJS + VITE preview - See white screen with error

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vite

I am tryining to fix an issue with white screen after make build and upload to production or make a build and run VITE preview. For example. When I do build with VITE and after that run command vite preview I can brows my app on localhost (http://localhost:4173/) but only firstime when I enter to localhost page, I see only white screen with console error "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) index.43ds234a.js:1". After the page refresh everything works well. What I explored is that when I see the error in console, the application trying to show old index.html with old files, but after refresh page everything is ok. Same behaviour is on production when I copy build to my server.

Is there anybody what has this similar issue, and can help me?

Thank you.

Some information:

Vuejs version: "2.7.10",
VITE version: "3.1.6",
npm version: "8.1.2",
node version: "v16.13.1"

My vite.confing.js

```
{
server: {
  port: '8080',
},
resolve: {
  alias: {
    '@': path.resolve(__dirname, './src'),
    'vue/types': 'vue-types/shim',
    AutoNumeric: 'node_modules/autonumeric/dist/autoNumeric.min.js',
  },
  extensions: ['.mjs', '.js', '.ts', '.jsx', '.tsx', '.json', '.vue'],
},
define: {
  'process.env': process.env,
},
test: {
  globals: true,
  environment: 'jsdom'
},
plugins: [
  vue(),
  createSvgPlugin(),
  dynamicImport(),
  VitePWA({
    registerType: 'autoUpdate',
    manifest: { name: 'Strategy in Action', theme_color: '#2f80ed' },
  }),
  viteSentry(sentryConfig),
  manifestSRI(),
],
build: {
  manifest: true,
  sourcemap: true,
  isDynamicEntry: true,
  rollupOptions: {
    output: {
      chunkFileNames: () => `assets/[name].${hash}.js`,
      entryFileNames: () => `[name].${hash}.js`,
      assetFileNames: () => `[name].${hash}[extname]`,
    },
  },
},
base: './',
baseUrl: './'
}
```

[image]